# Overlaying elements on image

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a grid containing an Image (with 2 rows top and bot that I will use later) and another grid containing 4 radio button.

When user click on image, a cross is displayed on the point where he clicked.

There is a part of code :

```
<Grid Grid.Column="2">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Grid.Row="0"
           x:Name="ImageViewer"
           Source="{Binding Picture}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
           MouseDown="Image_MouseDown"
           MouseMove="ImageViewer_MouseMove"
           MouseUp="Image_MouseUp"/>

    <local:Cross Grid.Row="0"
                 CenterPoint="{Binding Point1}"
                 Foreground="Red"/>

    <!-- Grid.Row="1" - Grid with RadioButtons -->
</Grid>
```

With events :

```
protected bool StartMove = false;
private void Image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
    {
        StartMove = true;
        Point p = e.GetPosition(ImageViewer);
        DrawPoint(p);
    }
}
private void Image_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
    {
        StartMove = false;
    }
}
private void ImageViewer_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && StartMove)
    {
        Point p = e.GetPosition(ImageViewer);
        DrawPoint(p);
    }
}
```

When image is perfectly sized (no border), the cross is correctly drawn. Clicking on my cat eye made this :

[image]

But if I resize my window, the cross is moving. I guess that the coordinates are computed considering the white spaces but I don't know how to prevent this.

There it is with the same point :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cross is drawn by `local:Cross` element. This element layout is matching to `Image` and you expect it to draw cross relative to `Image`.

And it does.

The problem is what `Image` (disregards it's stretching its size) also stretching its source image. You can try to set [Image.Stretch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx) to [Fill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx) or solve the problem  by using another layout (e.g. `Stretch="None"`, making position and size of `Cross` and `Image` equal).

Comment: I've try with `Stretch="None"`, it makes image very small (default size) and the cross is still in the white space. With `Stretch="Fill"` my image is deformed. At least best result is with `Stretch="UniformToFill"` but a part of Image get out from window

Comment: `Stretch="Fill"` should solve the problem. If you don't like it, then you can use `Stretch="None"`, make `Image` element autosize itself (to give you source image size), align `Cross` to it and put everything into `ViewBox` (to handle scaling yourself).

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is your image that is moving not the cross.
Your problem is that your are catching the position relative to Image UI element, so when you resize your main window you are also resizing your Image element.

Possible solutions:

- Fixed size Image element
- or, Recalculate the position of your cross when resize
- or, Keep your image aligned to top left in your Image

Comment: Keeping image on top left is not the prettiest solution, but it is the simplest. My points are saved with coordinates based on image, If I want to center the image, I will have to recalculate coordinates base on the grid each times. I will try but the top/left solution seems to be easier.